# Why are the deity and devotee called by the same name 'Swami Ayyappa' in Sabarimala?

Tags: belief, temple, ayyappa

Sabarimala temple is a famous temple in South India which is located in the state of Kerala. See the [website1](http://sabarimala.kerala.gov.in/). Many people visit the temple every year during the pilgrim season. Swami Ayyappa is the deity here and all except women between 10-50 age group can visit the temple with the 41 days vratha is strictly followed.

The biggest difference from other temples is that here the devotees are called by the same name as the deity; that is both are called Swami Ayyappa(Lord Ayyappa). Why are the devotees also called by the same name as the God?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see a quote which is showing in front of temple , "tatwamasi" . This simply means that "It's you". The concept of adwaitha (non-duality) shows here. By saying the same name "Ayyappa" together, it shows that we all, including the lord Ayyappa, are equal. The same Brahman exist in each and everyone  of us.

Comment: Why is it done in Ayyapa temples alone and not in temples of other deities?

Comment: Lord ayyappa considered as the supreme knowledge in Vedanta.

Comment: @KiranRS I would like to a citation for the claim that Ayyappa is condiered supreme knowledge in Vedanta.